# Once filtered, save object to component.ts

Tags: angular

In my component.ts, I have a service that returns data that I save in the myData variable.

```
myData: AllData[]=[];
```

and then on myData I get data from a service.

Now this data I display on a table in my html :

```
 <tr *ngFor="let row of myData| filterPipe:date ">
```

But as you can see here I filter by date.
Now this filtered object, I want to be able to access in my component.ts, because I need it for exporting.
How do I save the filtered object and send to my component.ts ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest filtering on the service, instead of using a pipe. Think of pipes more as data formatters.